# How come plasmon resonances of metals are capable of being tuned to different wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nanoscience

I read in this [article](http://www.caltech.edu/news/new-technique-could-harvest-more-suns-energy-44923) that plasmon resonances though being a pre-determined property of a metal are capable of being tuned to other wavelengths when these same metals are made into tiny nanostructures.

What I am not getting is what property of metal nanostructure helps to tune wavelengths of plasmon resonances of a particular metal.